# What is the solution to the dilemma of DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR?

Tags: php

I currently do this at the top of every script of mine:

```
require_once __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'interal' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'kickstart.php';
```

kickstart.php starts my own PHP framework/library which I have made. I used to do this:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../../../interal/kickstart.php';
```

Looks a million times better, huh? And on top of it, Windows understands / directory separators, even mixed / and \ in the same path, so everything is golden, no? We can all just use the lovely / which is also consistent with URLs in browsers! Yay! Everything is beautiful and logical and nice...

Except there's that darn DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR constant, which translates to / or \ or possibly others depending on the operating system. Just like PHP_EOL turns into either \r\n, \n or \r depending on the OS.

This ***bugs*** me, in a major way. You can think it's silly/stupid/insane, but it really does bug me beyond words. I went so far as to turn every single path in my entire code into using DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. Now I have "correct" code but which looks very ugly. I'm truly "on the fence" about this; I can see both sides equally much.

What happens if there is a new operating system which is not based on Windows or Unix and goes out of its way to be different for the sake of dropping all kinds of legacy madness? What if it uses # or . or something for separating directories? Assuming that PHP would be ported to this new OS, all existing PHP code which doesn't use DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR would break!

(Perhaps the real reason I'm so concerned about this is that I *wish* for such an OS to appear, because I'm sick of the existing ones.)

What is the best thing to do? I know that most will probably say "just use /", but since the constant exists, I can't do that. I thought of making my own constant which is an alias for DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, maybe called DS:

```
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

require_once __DIR__ . DS . '..' . DS . '..' . DS . '..' . DS . 'interal' . DS . 'kickstart.php';
```

Still not too pretty...

Would be very nice to hear some serious and insightful thoughts on this. Ideally, there is some way which I've not thought of which neatly solves this dilemma in a way which is both correct and looks good and is easy to input.

Comment: Hmmm...if I recall correctly, `/` works as a path separator on both Linux and any remotely recent version of Windows.  So, why not just use `/`?

Comment: Sometimes I wonder if bots are replying to my questions, because my question contains the reasoning for why not just use /?

Comment: On which other OS do you really expect to run your PHP script?  I'm not a bot, but I spend a lot of time on this site and sometimes feel this way :-)

Comment: `/` worked ever since MS-DOS 2.0, when directory support came along. No shame in going with the times; or accepted standards.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a helper function to substitute "/" to "\" when the OS changes, comparing if the DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR constant is different than the default that your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Use `join`

```
$path = join(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, array('root', 'lib', 'file.php');
```

From https://www.php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php

Answer (score 0):

If a new OS comes out that decides to use an entirely different file system convention you simply won't be able to compile any existing piece of software to run on it, including the PHP interpreter. Porting software to new operating systems is complex time-consuming work that needs to be done explicitly unless the target OS already provides a proper compatibility subsystem of some kind. In short:

- Brand new OS comes out, PHP cannot run: there's nothing you can do.
- Brand new OS comes out, PHP runs: there's hopefully nothing you need to do.

Regarding what I believe the root problem is (hard to write and denormalised paths), there're some additional techniques you can try:

- Stick to `/` as coding convention since it's both concise and the only cross-platform syntax.
- Considering replacing `..` with [dirname()](https://php.net/dirname)'s second argument to simplify relative paths.

  ```
  require_once __DIR__ . '/../../../interal/kickstart.php';
  ```

  becomes:

  ```
  require_once dirname(__DIR__, 3) . '/interal/kickstart.php';
  ```
- Normalise paths with [realpath()](https://php.net/realpath) whenever you need to print them out for user or make comparisons. It also accounts nicely for drive letters and `\\SHARENAME` prefixes in Windows shares. (This method only works with paths that actually exist.)